# Converting string amount value with parenthesis to double

Tags: c#, string, format, money-format

Example of my string value

```
string amtStr = "{100,000,000.00}";
```

Expected result/output

```
double amt = -100,000,000.00
```

What I've tried but it gives me error `"Cannot convert from 'string' to 'System.IFormatProvider'"`

```
Convert.ToDouble(txtAmount.Text.ToString("#,0.00;-#,0.00"))
```

Comment: Maybe the downvoter would like to comment? I feel that downvoting this question is a little harsh. It's clear as to requirements, and includes an attempt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try this code**

```
        string amtStr = "{100,000,000.00}";
        amtStr = amtStr.Replace("{", "-").Replace("}", "").Replace("(", "-").Replace(")", "").Trim() ;
        double amt = Convert.ToDouble(amtStr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Without replacing that braces {} this by default cannot be converted.  If it was a proper accounting number format then you can use NumberStyles like this

```
string amtStr = "(100,000,000.00)";
NumberStyles styles = NumberStyles.AllowParentheses | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingSign | NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;
string outputStr = double.Parse(amtStr, styles).ToString("#,0.00;-#,0.00");
double outputDbl = double.Parse(outputStr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the title of the question, maybe what you need is:

```
amt = Double.Parse(amtStr.Trim("{}".ToCharArray()))
```

Here, we remove leading and trailing `{` and `}`s and then parse the resulting string to a double using `Double.Parse`. `ToCharArray` is included so we can specify chars to be removed as one string rather than a char array.

Comment: The result should be negative